# Extract rows, with maximum and not value in a column, using SQL for MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have  a table in mysql like this:

```
+----+------+-----------+----+----+-----+
| id | vers | doc       | pr | dd | f   |
+----+------+-----------+----+----+-----+
| 1  | 1    | doc1.pdf  | 1  | 1  | neg |
+----+------+-----------+----+----+-----+
| 2  | 1    | other.pdf | 1  | 3  | pos |
+----+------+-----------+----+----+-----+
| 3  | 1    | bo.pdf    | 1  | 6  | ok  |
+----+------+-----------+----+----+-----+
| 4  | 2    | doc2.pdf  | 1  | 1  | pos |
+----+------+-----------+----+----+-----+
```

As you can see, the rows with id 1 and 4 have the same `pr` and `dd` value, but with a different `vers`.

I want retrieve all rows and if I have more rows with the same `pr` and `dd` I want get only the row with the maximum value inside the `vers` column.

So in this example, I want the row with id 2, 3 and 4.

Can I do that using an SQL query?
If yes, how?

Comment: (SELECT MAX(vers), pr, dd FROM foo GROUP BY pr, dd) gives you the max version you can then join using pr and dd to a select * FROM foo and keep the lines where vers = the max

Comment: @RC. He wants the entire row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a sub-query that returns each pr/dd combo's max vers. Join with that result:

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
join (select pr, dd, max(vers) as vers
      from tablename
      group by pr, dd) t2
  on t1.pr = t2.pr
  and t1.dd = t2.dd
  and t1.vers = t2.vers
```